# Populate a Bean from Other Bean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I wanted to populate bean from other bean.

```
 Example:

 // this is mapped to db using hibernate.
 class A {
    string name;
    string age;
    Date dateA;
    B obj;
 }

 // this was mapped to db but now I'd like to populate it from class A member dateA;
 class B{
    Date date;
 }
```

When I try to set B Object, I got nullpointerexception. Any idea how to process this issue?

Comment: how you are setting the `B` object?

Answer (score 1):

Dozer is a Java Bean to Java Bean mapper that recursively copies data from one object to another.

```
Mapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
DestinationObject destObject =  mapper.map(sourceObject, DestinationObject.class);
```

For more information, follow
[Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/gettingstarted.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should instantiate `B Obj = new B()` before invoking  `obj.setDate()` .

If you are already doing this, If i am missing something please provide sufficient info in the question.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html) has several different methods to accomplish your goal.

You could use `BeanUtils.copyProperties()`. There is also `BeanUtils.cloneBean()`.

Answer (score 0):

A very popular library to do this sort of mapping is [Apache commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/).

It has got comprehensive set of functionality to copy one bean properties to another.

You can go through usage examples [here](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/package-summary.html#package_description) and [here](https://discursive.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CJCOOK/Working+with+Beans%3a+Commons+BeanUtils).